# How to dockeriz a static website using HUGO?

Tags: docker, hugo

I have a simple static website, which I can host it from docker by writing a dockerfile.txt with the following commands

```
FROM nginx  
RUN mkdir /usr/share/nginx/html/blog 
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html/blog
```

This works pretty well for me.

Now I'm trying to dockerize a static that was build using docker, what should I exactly write in the docker file

```
FROM klakegg/hugo
COPY ?????????????????????
```

Does hugo have a dir where I can place the website files in it? or does Hugo works completely diff?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a 'Using image' section on https://hub.docker.com/r/klakegg/hugo/

Answer (score 3):

Your files need to be placed in `/src`

The `klakegg/hugo` container only acts as the "compiler". In order to host the generated files you also need nginx.

This can the achieved with [multistage-builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#name-your-build-stages)

```
FROM klakegg/hugo AS build
COPY . /src

FROM nginx  
COPY --from=build /src/public /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: That worked - but I'm not able to access the website now. So the URL to access is localhost:8082/blog/src/index.html (as I have copied the static website to the src folder)?
Also the container appears to be not running (Windows 10 Docker for desktop) .

Comment: I updated my example to also include nginx